# Receiving JSON data from an Ajax post request but only after I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to populate a table cell with JSON data. The post is working well and getting data in JSON encoded format in PHP. But the data does not load on ready function instead it loads when I press refresh button of the browser.

Below is my code

```
$("table.pme-main th:nth-child(3)").after('<th class="pme-header aligncenter">Short Name</th>');    

var url = '../management/getzones.php';   

var tourid = <?php echo $_GET['PME_sys_rec'] ?>;

var formData = { tourid: tourid };

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, field){
            $("table.pme-main td:nth-child(3)").eq(i).after('<td class="pme-cell-1 aligncenter">&nbsp;'+field+'</td>');
        });
    },    
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false 
});
```

Comment: When should the code be executed? If you want it "on ready" then you should wrap `$(function) {});` around your code: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Need to inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Is `tourid` defined first time? Any errors in browser console? Something is different in each instance and you need to isolate what that is

Comment: Maybe `tourid` doesn't get the right value and maybe the first time `$_GET['PME_sys_rec']` doesn't have any value...